# Should I comment the declaration or the definition in C++?

Tags: c++, comments

Which is more practical to comment, the declaration (in the header file) or the definition (in the source file)? Maybe I should comment both, or comment neither and put it all in a separate file...

Comment: I'm not saying the selected answer is wrong (I agree with it), but I've no idea how someone can accept a non-empirical answer four minutes after asking it.

Comment: Made sense to me when I read it... Isn't that the point of this site? If it wasn't, then the asker wouldn't be able to choose the answer.

Comment: Sure, but after 4 mins how do you know that a better or more insightful answer won't appear. I just found it strange, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can change the answer quite easily should I see a better one. Surely this would be better discussed on UserVoice? May I suggest the title, "Force users to wait more than 4 minutes before choosing an answer." ;-)

Comment: Hey Nick, after you already accepted an answer the chance somebody else will feel the urge to answer is going down to zero. Anyway I'm glad you liked my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should completely document the header file with highest priority.

Comments in the definition should be concentrated on implementation details, while header comments should be concentrated on the interface.

A third source of documentation, as you suggested, is useful as well. It should describe the overall concept.

A big plus of commenting header files is that you can create documentation automatically from them if you adhere to some simple syntax. Say hello to [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl)!

Comment: Comment public or protected class members in the header.  The private members are part of the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add to ypnos's answer:

Where your comments go depends upon who your audience is.  Thinking about your code as being closed-source helps in this regard: maintainers get to see the implementation, customers/users only get to see the interface.  If the comment is necessary for users, it must go in the interface.  If the comment is only relevant to the given implementation, it probably only needs to go into the implementation (but not necessarily, depending on your audience).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the comment says, and who you expect to read it.